# Less cliche way to say "hills and the valleys of my life"

Tags: word-choice

I am trying to craft the following sentence in a way that sounds a lot less cliche.

Any ideas?

> "The ability to write has been a gift that has gotten me through the
>   hills and the valleys of my life"

Comment: Why do you need to get through the "hills"?

Comment: *Ups and downs* is simpler, and somewhat less clichéd.

Comment: You know... I think you are right. No reason to put it there!

Comment: You might get rid of "the ability to" and just go with "Writing has gotten me through some tough times."

Comment: Consider *difficult times* or *difficult moments*.

Comment: Now, if the OP had substituted "sing" for "write" then that would have been far more on point and especially meaningful to the compatriots of Dame Shirley and Sir Tom!

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you try **VICISSITUDES**.? It sounds a lot less workaday than HILLS AND VALLEYS or UPS AND DOWNS

vi·cis·si·tude

\və-ˈsi-sə-ˌtüd, vī-, -ˌtyüd\

noun

1 a : the quality or state of beingchangeable : mutability 
b : natural change or mutation visiblein nature or in human affairs2 a : a favorable or unfavorable eventor situation that occurs by chance : afluctuation of state or condition  
b : a difficulty or hardship attendanton a way of life, a career, or a courseof action and usually beyond one'scontrol 
c : alternating change : succession

Comment: I think I prefer the cliches.

Comment: While that word is now my new favorite vocabulary word (who would have thought that there would be a word just for that) I am using these for admissions essays, and there is no way they will believe I have that kind of command of English. Still, thankyou!

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth, I quite agree with you. Sometimes the clichés sound better...only that the questioner is desperately trying to avoid them.

Comment: user200193 Quite so! Life is a cliche, if you ask me. Otherwise I'd offer "peaks" and troughs", but that sounds almost as good as vicissitudes.

Answer (score 1):

I would use either one of the following as a more simple alternative:

> The ability to write has been a gift that has gotten me through the highs and lows in life.

or

> The ability to write has been a gift that has gotten me through the roller coaster that is my life

Comment: ... through a/the roller coaster? I've found no internet examples for 'through the roller coaster that is my life'; people often add  'ride' (though 'through the roller coaster of life' _is_ used).

Comment: "through the roller coaster that is my life" is valid; kind of like "the mess that is my life" or "the unending mayhem that is my life", etc etc.

Comment: But I'm saying that 'through the roller coaster that is my life' has an uncomfortable juxtaposition of 'through' and 'roller coaster' (and Google results seem to indicate is non-idiomatic).